# local-index and partition-key on same column of a table

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle10g, partitioning

I had a table which was having a global index(b-tree) on a date column.
We created range partition on it for a better retrieval performance. The partition key we used is the same column which has indexes on it.
Later we moved the global indexes to local by dropping the recreating the local index on same date column.

Now we have local index and partition key on same column.But after this the dataload into this table is taking three times more of the usual time

What could be the reason that if the partition key and local index are on the same column of the table then the dataload takes more time?
When we checked the explain plan , we figured that the queries are not using local indexes. why it does not use the local index in this case?
is there any hidden inbuilt indexes attached with the partion key as well , which oracle uses in place of the local index?
What could be solution to this so the performance of dataload doesnot get impacted?
Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you gathered statistics on the new index? When an index isn't being used that's a common problem.

Comment: Yes bob. We have gathered statistics on the table using GATHER_TABLE_STATS , both with granularity => 'PARTITION' and GRANULARITY=>'ALL'

Comment: we have also gathered statitics on the index. checked the last_analyzed column of the dba_indexes table as well